# Is this question suitable for SO?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I just noticed this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24821801/can-programs-write-their-own-code), and I see the guide in the help center that [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development?). So do you think it is suitable for SO?

Comment: No, it's not suitable. Marked it as `too broad`.

Comment: Doesn't look like.  As an aside, the number of upvotes on a post often put you in doubt as to what is off-topic or low quality or not an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not.

Questions like that are off-topic for two reasons: they are too broad and (though this varies with how they are asked) they are usually unclear.

The question goes wrong in these ways:

1. It's asking about an entire field: that's *way* too broad.
2. It's explicitly asking for someone to write code without any in the question: that's normally not a good sign.
3. It's asking whether something `is possible`, which is almost guaranteed to attract comments along the lines of `Yes, of course it's possible.`.
4. It's poorly formatted and has grammar issues (quite common).

As you can see, it generated a number of off-topic and link-only answers, which is to be expected of this kind of question. It was also put on hold as too broad, which I'm guessing was your thought in the first place. You're right that [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) is  a great resource and it doesn't hurt to point people to it when you see a question that's off-topic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I get some point.

Comment: @Tony I'm glad it helped.